# Alexa accepting wrong values for built-in slot type

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Alexa is accepting incorrect values for a built-in slot value. I want the slot type to be AMAZON.Color, but it appears that alexa is just accepting anything. Shouldn't alexa reprompt if it receives a value for the slot that is not a valid color? I am not sure what to do at this point.

[Alexa developer console screenshot, slot type is AMAZON.Color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTd3z.png)

[JSON output, alexa is acceptin 'aaa' as a color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8O2ie.png)

I want alexa to only accept values that are in AMAZON.Color for this slot

Comment: You can create a custom slot called colors and add as many possible color values as you see needed as values, I would also go here https://forums.developer.amazon.com/topics/uservoice.html and let the Alexa developer team know that AMAZON.color is broken, It is certainly not the only pre-defined slot that has been buggy of late AMAZON.animal accepted Desk and chair as animal types.

Comment: Oh okay so that really is the only way then. Thanks!